# I can't send data view to controller in ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: post, controller, asp.net-core-mvc, testbox

That is my view:

```
@model DBYTest.Models.TblDebitEnter

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Debit Register";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    @*    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css"> *@
    <style>
        .login-dark {
            height: 1000px;
            background-image: url('/DebitBG.jpg');
            background-size: cover;
            position: relative;
            background-repeat: repeat;
        }

            .login-dark table td {
                color: white; /* Metin rengini beyaz olarak ayarlar */
            }

            .login-dark form {
                max-width: 1000px;
                width: 92%;
                background-color: #1e2833;
                padding: 10px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                position: absolute;
                top: 30%;
                left: 50%;
                color: #fff;
                box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,45);
                line-height: 1.5;
            }

            .login-dark .illustration {
                text-align: center;
                padding: 15px 0 20px;
                font-size: 100px;
                color: #2980ef;
            }

            .login-dark form .form-control {
                background: none;
                border: none;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #434a52;
                border-radius: 0;
                box-shadow: none;
                outline: none;
                color: inherit;
            }

            .login-dark form .btn-primary {
                background: #214a80;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 4px;
                padding: 11px;
                box-shadow: none;
                margin-top: 26px;
                text-shadow: none;
                outline: none;
            }

                .login-dark form .btn-primary:hover, .login-dark form .btn-primary:active {
                    background: #214a80;
                    outline: none;
                }

            .login-dark form .forgot {
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #6f7a85;
                opacity: 0.9;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

                .login-dark form .forgot:hover, .login-dark form .forgot:active {
                    opacity: 1;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }

            .login-dark form .btn-primary:active {
                transform: translateY(1px);
            }

            .login-dark form .form-group {
                margin-bottom: 0.001px; /* Başlıklar arasındaki boşluğu azaltır */
                margin-bottom: 0.01px; /* Başlıklar ile giriş alanları arasındaki dikey boşluğu daraltır */
                margin-top: 0.1px; /* Giriş alanları ile bir sonraki başlık arasındaki dikey boşluğu daraltır */
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="/Debit/DebitRegister" method="post">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="login-dark">
            <h1>Debit Register</h1>



            @using (Html.BeginForm("Debit", "DebitRegister", FormMethod.Post))
            {

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        @*  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <span>Barkod No</span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BarkodNo)
                    </div> *@

                        <div style="display: flex;">
                            <table width="20%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Barkod No</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BarkodNo)</td>
                                    <td>Demirbaş Türü</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DemirbasTuru)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Marka</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Marka)</td>
                                    <td>Model</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Ürün Seri No</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UrunSeriNo)</td>
                                    <td>IMEINo</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Imeino)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>MACAdres1</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Macadres1)</td>
                                    <td>MACAdres2</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Macadres2)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tedarikçi Firma</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TedarikciFirma)</td>
                                    <td>Demirbaş Durumu</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DemirbasDurumu)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Lokasyon</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Lokasyon)</td>
                                    <td>Raf Sıra No</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RafSiraNo)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Yazılım/Sistem</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.YazilimSistem)</td>
                                    <td>Sipariş No</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SiparisNo)</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="20%">
                            </table>
                            <table width="20%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>FaturaTarihi</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FaturaTarihi)</td>
                                    <td>Temin Tarihi</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TeminTarihi)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Son Kullanma Tarihi</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SonKullanmaTarihi)</td>
                                    <td>GarantiBitisTarihi</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GarantiBitisTarihi)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>ServisHizmeti</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ServisHizmeti)</td>
                                    <td>Ek Demirbas</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EkDemirbas)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Açıklama</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Aciklama)</td>
                                    <td>CAPEX</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Capex)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>OPEX</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Opex)</td>
                                    <td>DuranVarlik</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DuranVarlik)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Yatırım</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Yatirim)</td>
                                    <td>GarantiBitisTarihi</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GarantiBitisTarihi)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Lisans Etiketi</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LisansEtiketi)</td>
                                    <td>Creadate</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Creadate)</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Fatura Tutarı</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FaturaTutari)</td>
                                    <td>Zimmetli Personel</td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ZimmetliPersonel)</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Kaydet</button>

            }


            <!-- Diğer veri girişi alanlarını burada gruplayarak ekleyin -->
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my controller:

```
using DBYTest.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DBYTest.Controllers
{
    public class DebitController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<DebitController> _logger;
        private readonly DemirbasYonetimiContext _db;

        public DebitController(ILogger<DebitController> logger, DemirbasYonetimiContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        // GET: /DebitRegister
        public IActionResult DebitRegister()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Home/Debit/DebitRegister.cshtml");
        }

        // POST: /DebitRegister
        [HttpPost]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DebitRegister(TblDebitEnter model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Yeni kullanıcıyı oluşturun
                var debit = new TblDebitEnter
                {
                    Id = model.Id,
                    BarkodNo = model.BarkodNo,
                    DemirbasTuru = model.DemirbasTuru,
                    Marka = model.Marka,
                    Model = model.Model,
                    UrunSeriNo = model.UrunSeriNo,
                    Imeino = model.Imeino,
                    Macadres1 = model.Macadres1,
                    Macadres2 = model.Macadres2,
                    TedarikciFirma = model.TedarikciFirma,
                    DemirbasDurumu = model.DemirbasDurumu,
                    Lokasyon = model.Lokasyon,
                    RafSiraNo = model.RafSiraNo,
                    YazilimSistem = model.YazilimSistem,
                    SiparisNo = model.SiparisNo,
                    FaturaTarihi = model.FaturaTarihi,
                    TeminTarihi = model.TeminTarihi,
                    SonKullanmaTarihi = model.SonKullanmaTarihi,
                    GarantiBitisTarihi = model.GarantiBitisTarihi,
                    FaturaTutari = model.FaturaTutari,
                    ZimmetliPersonel = model.ZimmetliPersonel,
                    ServisHizmeti = model.ServisHizmeti,
                    EkDemirbas = model.EkDemirbas,
                    Aciklama = model.Aciklama,
                    Capex = model.Capex,
                    Opex = model.Opex,
                    DuranVarlik = model.DuranVarlik,
                    Yatirim = model.Yatirim,
                    LisansEtiketi = model.LisansEtiketi,
                    Creadate = DateTime.Now,
                    ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    Owner = model.Owner
                    
                    // Diğer özellikleri buraya ekleyin
                };

                // Kullanıcıyı veritabanına ekleyin
                _db.TblDebitEnters.Add(debit);
                _db.SaveChanges();

                // Kayıt işlemi başarılıysa, başka bir sayfaya yönlendirin
                return RedirectToAction("DebitRegister");
            }

            // Kayıt işlemi başarısız olduysa veya model geçerli değilse, tekrar kayıt formunu gösterin
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

My context is full true, I don't get any error in program, but I can't get data from view to controller. When I check with a breakpoint and try to save some data in my view page, every time data is null, I just want to get data from view with a table and save it to my database.

Is anyone able to help me?

Comment: You have nested forms in your view, which is not valid HTML and can cause issues. You start a form with the `<form>` tag, and then inside this form, you have another form started with `@using (Html.BeginForm(...))`. You should remove one of the forms. make sure that the property names in the `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PropertyName)` match exactly with the properties of the `TblDebitEnter` model.try setting action and controller name  `Html.BeginForm("DebitRegister", "Debit", FormMethod.Post)`